# SVG feComposite filter implementation in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, svg-filters

I'm working on a SVG filters implementation in canvas but i have two problems with the composite arithmetic operator.

My implementation for this operator is based on [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feCompositeElement) and firefox9 source code.

Here my code for this filter & svg exemple : [Fiddle complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/cv1bLcmn/15/)

```
var k1Scaled = options.k1 / 255;
var k4Scaled = options.k4 * 255;
for(v=0; v<datas.length; v+=4) {
   r = datasB1[v+0];
   g = datasB1[v+1];
   b = datasB1[v+2];
   a = datasB1[v+3];
   r1 = datasB2[v+0];
   g1 = datasB2[v+1];
   b1 = datasB2[v+2];
   a1 = datasB2[v+3];
   //if (a === 0 && a1 === 0) continue;
   vR = k1Scaled * r1 * r + options.k2 * r + options.k3 * r1 + k4Scaled;
   vG = k1Scaled * g1 * g + options.k2 * g + options.k3 * g1 + k4Scaled;
   vB = k1Scaled * b1 * b + options.k2 * b + options.k3 * b1 + k4Scaled;
   vA = k1Scaled * a1 * a + options.k2 * a + options.k3 * a1 + k4Scaled;
   datas[v+0] = Math.min(Math.max(0, ~~vR), 255);
   datas[v+1] = Math.min(Math.max(0, ~~vG), 255);
   datas[v+2] = Math.min(Math.max(0, ~~vB), 255);
   datas[v+3] = Math.min(Math.max(0, ~~vA), 255);
}
```

My first problem : I have silver color on transparent pixel due to the formula, if i decompose the formula on transparent pixel, the result is :

result = k1*i1*i2 + k2*i1 + k3*i2 + k4

where k1 = 0.5 / 255 = 0.0019, i1 = 0, i2 =0, k2 = 0.5, k3 = 0.5, k4 = 0.5 * 255 = 127

result = 0.0019*0*0 + 0.5*0 + 0.5*0 + 127 = 127 => silver on rgba

My second problem : my result is more opaque than svg exemple, i suppose webbrowser pre-multiply the rgba result but i try this but no result.

I can't use svg filter applied on canvas, i need pure javascript/canvas implementation.

If you have an idea or solution thank in advance.

Kran.

Comment: Why can't you use svg filter applied on canvas? You know you can set your [context's filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) to point to an svg one in the document `ctx.filter = 'url(#yourSvgFilter)'`

Comment: Thank Michael, Kaiido, only chrome can apply correctly multiple svg filter on canvas, firefox and ie crash, that's is the reason of my implementation in pure javascript

Comment: If FF crashes, then open a bug report on bugzilla.

Comment: @kran Sorry my bad for adding the porterDuff "over" it is not needed. But that does not get rid of the black. I would say that it is the canvas, it makes all transparent pixels black, your images have colour in the RGB where there are transparent pixels. But on further testing, and cheating (Using Raw pixel data from file side stepping canvas) my answer is miles out for some values of k1,k2,k3,k4 so I will retract it. Sorry I could not help.

Comment: Ps : for me it doesn't crash at all https://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/cv1bLcmn/20/

Comment: @Kaiido, my exemple don"t crash firefox or IE.
Try [this](http://w3.eleqtriq.com/2015/05/the-svg-filter-and-why-its-awesome/) on firefox.

Comment: @kran which one ? And once again, if you've found a bug in FF, please [file a bug report](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). ([This  one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBwbJP) and [this other one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpoaRj) do work on my FF, didn't tried any other)

Answer (score 1):

[Here the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/cv1bLcmn/26/)

```
this._arithmetic = function(options, ctx) {
  var b1, ctxB1, ctxB2, w, h, x, y, v, imgDatas, datas, imgDatasB1, datasB1, imgDatasB2, datasB2;
  b1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  ctxB1 = b1.getContext("2d");
  ctxB1.resize(this.width,this.height);
  ctxB1.drawImage(options.in.source, options.in.options.x, options.in.options.y, options.in.options.width, options.in.options.height);
  imgDatasB1 = ctxB1.getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height);
  this.premultiply(imgDatasB1);
  datasB1 = imgDatasB1.data;

  b2 = document.createElement("canvas");
  ctxB2 = b2.getContext("2d");
  ctxB2.resize(this.width,this.height);
  ctxB2.drawImage(options.in2.source, options.in2.options.x, options.in2.options.y, options.in2.options.width, options.in2.options.height);
  ctx.resize(this.width,this.height);
  ctx.drawImage(b2, 0, 0);
  imgDatas = ctx.getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height);
  this.premultiply(imgDatas);
  datas = imgDatas.data;
  var k1Scaled = options.k1 / 255;
  var k4Scaled = options.k4 * 255;
  var vR,vG,vB,vA,r,g,b,a,r1,g1,b1,a1;
  for(v = 0;v < datas.length;v += 4) {
    r = datasB1[v + 0];
    g = datasB1[v + 1];
    b = datasB1[v + 2];
    a = datasB1[v + 3];

    r1 = datas[v + 0];
    g1 = datas[v + 1];
    b1 = datas[v + 2];
    a1 = datas[v + 3];

    vR = k1Scaled * r1 * r + options.k2 * r + options.k3 * r1 + k4Scaled;
    vG = k1Scaled * g1 * g + options.k2 * g + options.k3 * g1 + k4Scaled;
    vB = k1Scaled * b1 * b + options.k2 * b + options.k3 * b1 + k4Scaled;
    vA = k1Scaled * a1 * a + options.k2 * a + options.k3 * a1 + k4Scaled;

    vR = vR < 0 ? 0 : vR > 255 ? 255 : vR;
    vG = vG < 0 ? 0 : vG > 255 ? 255 : vG;
    vB = vB < 0 ? 0 : vB > 255 ? 255 : vB;
    vA = vA < 0 ? 0 : vA > 255 ? 255 : vA;

    datas[v + 0] = vR;
    datas[v + 1] = vG;
    datas[v + 2] = vB;
    datas[v + 3] = vA;
  }
  this.unPremultiply(imgDatas);
  ctx.putImageData(imgDatas,0,0);
};
```

the code of premultiply/unPremultiply functions is in the fiddle link.